# Resizing a plot in Tkinter

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter, python-2.6

I am fooling around making a small program for some personal use with Tkinter, and it will contain a plot which needs to be resized if the window is resized. This works if I make the window smaller, however, if I increase the window size the plot stays the same size after it has reached some size (although it nicely sticks to the middle of the frame it is in). I tried both pack and grid, but I don't understand why it will resize any bigger ... Currently I set to original image to 21 by 13 inches (but I would like to know what prevents/prohibits it from resizing in the first place.

this is my code (I know its a bit bulky..)

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import misc
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


root = Tk()
root.title("Plotting Customers Lines")

content = ttk.Frame(root, padding=(3,3,12,12))
plot = ttk.Frame(root, padding=(3,3,12,12))
toolbarframe = ttk.Frame(root)

subject = StringVar(content)

dropdown = ttk.Combobox(content, textvariable = subject, values = ['To', 'Do', 'Later'])
ok = ttk.Button(content, text='Plot Timeline')

f = plt.figure(figsize=(21,13))
a = f.add_subplot(111)
a.plot(range(100),range(100))

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, plot)
canvas.show()

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, toolbarframe)
toolbar.update()

content.grid(column=1, row=0)
plot.grid(column=0,row=0)
toolbarframe.grid(column=0,row=1)

ok.grid(column=1, row=1)
dropdown.grid(column=1,row=0)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))#pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand = True)#grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))

root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight = 0)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight = 0)

plot.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
plot.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Someplace there is a missing call back which updates the figsize (in inches) when the window gets resized.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that could be. (As in, it sounds logical) but the resizing does work properly if the window is downsized, but not if gets bigger